# Read a single byte from large file

Tags: python, file

I have this function that I want to read a single byte from a large file. The only problem is that after a certain amount of file reads the memory on the pc jumps up from a steady 1.5gb to 4gb and higher depending on how many file reads. 
(I break at 80 files because higher would crash my pc)

All i want is to get the 1 byte and not the whole file. Help please.

```
    def mem_test():
        count = 0
        for dirpath, dnames, fnames in scandir.walk(restorePaths[0]):
            for f in fnames:
                if 'DIR.EDB' in f or 'PRIV.EDB' in f:
                    f = open(os.path.join(dirpath, f), 'rb')
                    f.read(1) #Problem line!
                    f.close()
                    if count > 80:
                        print 'EXIT'
                        sys.exit(1)                    
                    count += 1
mem_test()
```

Comment: So what happens on `#Problem line!`? An error? … do you need the return value?

Comment: Does it happen even if you don't read? Don't open? Don't iterate over `fnames`?

Comment: @JasonGray: Does your problem still occur, when you change manual opening/closing into `with` statement like mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)? It is safer that way: `with open(os.path.join(dirpath, f), 'rb') as f: f.read(1)`. Maybe you do not close these files, regardless of what we see here?

Comment: This really, really shouldn't make a difference, but you might want to try: (1) add `buffering=0` to the `open`. (2) same but `buffering=4096`. (3) replace the `open` with `os.open`: `fd = os.open(name, os.O_RDONLY); os.read(fd, 1); os.close(fd)`. (4) Instead of `read`, `mmap`: `m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 4096); m[0]` (or `fd` instead of `f.fileno()` to combine (3) and (4)). Any of these should only save on the order of 4-16KB, not gigabytes, but… it's worth testing.

Comment: If i remove the '#problem line' there is no memory issue. But obviously nothing is read

Comment: Does the memory usage actually jump, or does it increase gradually? If it jumps, can you isolate the particular file or iteration that causes memory usage to jump?

Comment: The indentation in this code doesn't look right. Can you recheck your indentation and see if it matches the source file you're testing the problem with?

Comment: Have you tried `f.flush()` before `f.close()` ?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the memory for the file isn't released from memory instantly, it seems to take a couple of seconds for it to clear. I tested this by adding a sleep(0.5) after every file read and it goes up but then down when the memory is released.

Comment: Are you using the scandir library from github? If so, how old is your code? There's a memory leak that sounds similar that was fixed about 2 months ago: https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/issues/6

Answer (score -1):

To address the memory issue, I think you'd want to use a generator:

```
def mem_test():
    for dirpath, dnames, fnames in scandir.walk(restorePaths[0]):
        for f in fnames:
            if 'DIR.EDB' in f or 'PRIV.EDB' in f:
                with open(os.path.join(dirpath, f), 'rb') as f:
                    yield f.read(1) #Problem line!

results = [x for x in mem_test()]
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote but I did try this and it had the same effect. sorry

Comment: This should actually use *more* memory than the questioner's sample code, since the sample doesn't save the `f.read` return value at all.

Comment: Interesting. That's confirmed.

Comment: @Brian Atm i'm just trying to figure out why it has this memory issue.

Comment: If you think this would make a difference, you should post an explanation of why.

Comment: @Gabe clearly, it does not. In my experience generators have been the way to solve memory issues. In this case, upon deeper investigation they are obviously not enough; the scandir library uses yield already, too.